# Failed to extend partition

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2012-r2, diskmanagement

I have a virtualised instance of Windows Server 2012 R2.

I changed the size of one of the underlying virtual disks from 800Gb to 2Tb.

I scanned the drives in Compmgmt and found that it was correctly seeing the new size.

I told disk management to extend the disk up to 2Tb. At this point it gave an error (which I failed to correctly note down, but was something like "the operation is not correct" or "operation failed, the parameter is not correct".)

Disk Management (before I closed it) was showing that the volume was now 2Tb.

The view from "This PC" shows the disk as still being 800Gb.

I then restarted the machine, hoping that one of these would correct itself.

After the restart the view in "This PC" still shows 800Gb and disk management refuses to show anything as it's trying to connect to the virtual disk service.

The virtual disk service (as per services.msc) is not running. Nor will it start (times out when trying).

Taking a look with DISKPART shows that the partition is 2Tb in size.

If anyone has any idea on how I can get everything to agree on the size of my partition and how to get the virtual disk service running it'd be greatly appreciated.

I also extended another partition on another disk on this host from 150Gb to 250Gb with no issues. The only differences between these disks are that the sizes on the one which worked are smaller and the failed one is using ReFS rather than NTFS.

EDIT as per @EdwinvanMierlo's request:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status  Size     Free     Dyn  GPT
  --------  ------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online   250 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online  2049 GB  1025 MB        *

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part

  Partition ###  Type     Size     Offset 
  -------------  -------  -------  ------
  Partition 1    Primary  2047 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info   
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  ------
  Volume 0         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 1     C                NTFS   Partition    249 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 2     D   ExchangeDat  ReFS   Partition   2047 GB  Healthy
```

Comment: question if you dont mind, since there is a tag in your question visualization, have you checked virual hard disk size, and your virtual application did extend the drive correctly

Comment: Can you update your question with diskpart "list disk" then select disk X then "list part" to list the partitions, and finally "list vol"

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna: The guest OS can correctly see that the underlying disk is 2Tb in size.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo: Updated as requested

Comment: @Ceisc First of all, back up your data, to ensure you can go back to a known good state, prior to trying to solve this. It has been known that ReFS does not extend to the full size of the extended partition. The work around is to extend it with small steps, repeatedly until fully extended. As I am not sure this is your particular situation, I am not posting this as an answer. Just to reitterate: **backup your data** prior to trying to solve this.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo: Luckily the system I was experiencing the issue with was just a clone of another system anyway, so I can just trash it and start over. I will make another copy and then try extending it a bit at a time and see whether it works. Do you have any references for the known ReFS issue?

Comment: @Ceisc I thought it would be easy to find those references, but it seems not. If/When I find them I will share.

Comment: @ceisc any update from your side?